# Can't get gradients from loaded model in tensorflow/keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I have a pre-trained model that I load and it effectively works (i.e. I can make predictions). I want to get the gradients of the model for a certain parameter, however I cannot manage to get any meaningful results. Always a `None`output.

My code:

```
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)

x = X_test[0].reshape(1,100)
y = np.reshape(Y_test[0], (1,1))
tf_y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y,dtype=np.float32)

model2 = ClassificationModel(config, logging).model
model2.load_weights("class_models/model.382-0.46-0.87.h5")

# predict real x_test
y_hat = model2.predict(x)
tf_y_hat = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_hat, dtype=np.float32)

loss = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(tf_y,tf_y_hat)
grad, = K.gradients(loss,x)

print(grad)
```

And the output I get for the print is `None`. What am I doing wrong? How do I get the gradient given my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, tensorflow cannot connect `x` to the computational graph of `loss` since `loss` is created from a numpy array (`y_hat`) and `x` is also just a numpy array. The following code should work instead:

```
tf_x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=np.float32)
loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(tf_y, model2(tf_x))
grad, = K.gradients(loss, tf_x)
```

Comment: How did you know x is a Numpy array? I am having similar problem with TensorFlow 2 where `x` is a TensorFlow tensor and the model was loaded back from `load_model`?